# Dynamic child communication

Tags: java, swing, listener, parent

Background: I have a JPanel (PanelCarga extends JPanel) that displays as many sub-JPanels (DatosArchivo extends JPanel) as files I wish to open (n DatosArchivo panels) in my program for diferent purposes. This DatosArchivos contains a "X" button that I wish it to closes this DatosArchivos panel and then informs to the corresponding PanelCarga that it have been closed so that can reorganize in his grid the remaining n-1 DatosArchivo panels.

Tha PanelCarga Class:

```
    package gui;

    import java.awt.GridLayout;
    import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
    import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
    import java.io.File;
    import java.sql.SQLException;
    import java.util.LinkedList;
    import javax.swing.GroupLayout;
    import javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment;
    import javax.swing.JButton;
    import javax.swing.JDialog;
    import javax.swing.JFileChooser;
    import javax.swing.JLabel;
    import javax.swing.JPanel;
    import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
    import javax.swing.JTextField;
    import javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement;
    import logica.Cargador;

    public class PanelCarga extends JPanel {
        /**
         * 
         */
        private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
        private JTextField textField;
        private final JPanel panel = new JPanel();

        /**
         * Create the panel.
         */
        public PanelCarga() {

            JLabel lblArchivosA = new JLabel("Archivo (-s) a cargar");

            textField = new JTextField();
            textField.setEditable(false);
            textField.setColumns(10);

            final JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane();

            scrollPane.setViewportView(panel);
            panel.setLayout(new GridLayout(0, 2, 0, 0));

            JButton btnAbrir = new JButton("Abrir");
            btnAbrir.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
                    JFileChooser escoger = new JFileChooser();
                    escoger.setMultiSelectionEnabled(true);
                    int resultado = escoger.showOpenDialog(null);
                    File[] archivos = null;
                    String nombres = "";

                    if (resultado == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION) {
                        archivos = escoger.getSelectedFiles();

                        for (int i = 0; i<archivos.length;i++){

                            if (i==0){
                                nombres = nombres + archivos [i].getName() ;
                            }else{
                                nombres = nombres + "; " +archivos [i].getName() ;
                            }                       

                            DatosArchivo datos = null;
                            try {
                                datos = new DatosArchivo();
                            } catch (SQLException e) {
                                JDialog error = new JDialog ();
                                error.setTitle("error");
                                JLabel mensaje = new JLabel(e.getMessage());
                                error.getContentPane().add(mensaje);
                                error.validate();                       
                            }
                            datos.textField_Ruta.setText(archivos[i].toString());
                            JTextField texto = new JTextField ();
                            texto.setBounds(10, 10, 100, 100);
                            panel.add(datos);

                        }

                        textField.setText(nombres);

                        panel.validate();
                        scrollPane.validate();
                    }


                }
            });


            GroupLayout groupLayout = new GroupLayout(this);
            groupLayout.setHorizontalGroup(
                groupLayout.createParallelGroup(Alignment.LEADING)
                    .addGroup(groupLayout.createSequentialGroup()
                        .addContainerGap()
                        .addGroup(groupLayout.createParallelGroup(Alignment.LEADING)
                            .addComponent(scrollPane, Alignment.TRAILING, GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, 430, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                            .addGroup(groupLayout.createSequentialGroup()
                                .addComponent(lblArchivosA)
                                .addGap(18)
                                .addComponent(textField, GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, 250, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                                .addPreferredGap(ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
                                .addComponent(btnAbrir)))
                        .addContainerGap())
            );
            groupLayout.setVerticalGroup(
                groupLayout.createParallelGroup(Alignment.LEADING)
                    .addGroup(groupLayout.createSequentialGroup()
                        .addGap(6)
                        .addGroup(groupLayout.createParallelGroup(Alignment.BASELINE)
                            .addComponent(lblArchivosA)
                            .addComponent(textField, GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                            .addComponent(btnAbrir))
                        .addPreferredGap(ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
                        .addComponent(scrollPane, GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, 423, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                        .addContainerGap())
            );



            setLayout(groupLayout);

        }

        public LinkedList <Cargador> getCargadores (){
            LinkedList <Cargador> cargadores = new LinkedList <Cargador> ();

            for (int i = 0; i < panel.getComponentCount(); i++){
                cargadores.add(((DatosArchivo) panel.getComponent(i)).getCargador());
            }

            return cargadores;
        }


        public JPanel getPanel (){
            return this.panel;      
        }

    }
```

And the DatosArchivo Class:

```
package gui;

import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import javax.swing.GroupLayout;
import javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JComboBox;
import javax.swing.JDialog;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JTextField;
import javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement;
import javax.swing.border.BevelBorder;
import logica.Cargador;
import logica.Conector;

public class DatosArchivo extends JPanel{
    /**
     * 
     */
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    public JTextField textField_Ruta;
    private JTextField textField_Anio;
    private JTextField textField_UbicacionNueva;
    private String usuario = "rpatrizio";
    private final JComboBox comboBox_Ubicacion ;
    private JComboBox comboBox_Dia;
    private JComboBox comboBox_mes;

    /**
     * Create the panel.
     * @throws SQLException 
     */
    public DatosArchivo() throws SQLException {
        setBorder(new BevelBorder(BevelBorder.LOWERED, null, null, null, null));

        JPanel panel = new JPanel();

        JLabel lblArchivo = new JLabel("Archivo:");

        textField_Ruta = new JTextField();
        textField_Ruta.setEditable(false);
        textField_Ruta.setColumns(10);
        GroupLayout gl_panel = new GroupLayout(panel);
        gl_panel.setHorizontalGroup(
            gl_panel.createParallelGroup(Alignment.LEADING)
                .addGroup(gl_panel.createSequentialGroup()
                    .addContainerGap()
                    .addComponent(lblArchivo)
                    .addPreferredGap(ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
                    .addComponent(textField_Ruta, GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, 190, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                    .addContainerGap())
        );
        gl_panel.setVerticalGroup(
            gl_panel.createParallelGroup(Alignment.LEADING)
                .addGroup(gl_panel.createSequentialGroup()
                    .addGap(5)
                    .addGroup(gl_panel.createParallelGroup(Alignment.BASELINE)
                        .addComponent(lblArchivo)
                        .addComponent(textField_Ruta, GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
                    .addContainerGap(GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE))
        );
        panel.setLayout(gl_panel);

        JPanel panel_1 = new JPanel();

        JLabel lblUbicación = new JLabel("Ubicaci\u00F3n");

        textField_UbicacionNueva = new JTextField();
        textField_UbicacionNueva.setEditable(false);
        textField_UbicacionNueva.setColumns(10);

        String [] ubicaciones = Conector.getUbicacion();
        comboBox_Ubicacion = new JComboBox(ubicaciones);
        comboBox_Ubicacion.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
                if (comboBox_Ubicacion.getSelectedItem().toString().equals("Agregar Nueva")){
                    textField_UbicacionNueva.setEditable(true);
                }else {
                    textField_UbicacionNueva.setEditable(false);
                }
            }
        });

        String [] dias = {"","01","02","03","04","05","06","07","08","09","10","11","12","13","14","15","16","17","18","19","20","21","22","23","24","25","26","27","28","29","30","31"};

        String [] meses = {"","enero","febrero","marzo","abril","mayo","junio","julio","agosto","septiembre","octubre","noviembre","diciembre"};

        JPanel panel_2 = new JPanel();
        GroupLayout groupLayout = new GroupLayout(this);
        groupLayout.setHorizontalGroup(
            groupLayout.createParallelGroup(Alignment.LEADING)
                .addGroup(groupLayout.createSequentialGroup()
                    .addContainerGap()
                    .addGroup(groupLayout.createParallelGroup(Alignment.LEADING)
                        .addComponent(panel, GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, 296, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                        .addComponent(panel_1, GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 296, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                        .addComponent(panel_2, GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 296, Short.MAX_VALUE))
                    .addContainerGap())
        );
        groupLayout.setVerticalGroup(
            groupLayout.createParallelGroup(Alignment.LEADING)
                .addGroup(groupLayout.createSequentialGroup()
                    .addGap(8)
                    .addComponent(panel, GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 31, GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                    .addPreferredGap(ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
                    .addComponent(panel_1, GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 32, GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                    .addPreferredGap(ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
                    .addComponent(panel_2, GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 34, GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                    .addGap(16))
        );

        JLabel lblFecha = new JLabel("Fecha");
        comboBox_Dia = new JComboBox(dias);

        JLabel lblDe = new JLabel("de");
        comboBox_mes = new JComboBox(meses);

        JLabel lblDe_1 = new JLabel("de");

        textField_Anio = new JTextField();
        textField_Anio.setColumns(10);

        JButton btnX = new JButton("X");
        btnX.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {

            }
        });

        GroupLayout gl_panel_2 = new GroupLayout(panel_2);
        gl_panel_2.setHorizontalGroup(
            gl_panel_2.createParallelGroup(Alignment.LEADING)
                .addGroup(gl_panel_2.createSequentialGroup()
                    .addContainerGap()
                    .addComponent(lblFecha)
                    .addPreferredGap(ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
                    .addComponent(comboBox_Dia, GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                    .addPreferredGap(ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
                    .addComponent(lblDe)
                    .addPreferredGap(ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
                    .addComponent(comboBox_mes, GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                    .addPreferredGap(ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
                    .addComponent(lblDe_1)
                    .addPreferredGap(ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
                    .addComponent(textField_Anio, GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 38, GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                    .addPreferredGap(ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
                    .addComponent(btnX)
                    .addGap(49))
        );
        gl_panel_2.setVerticalGroup(
            gl_panel_2.createParallelGroup(Alignment.LEADING)
                .addGroup(gl_panel_2.createSequentialGroup()
                    .addGap(5)
                    .addGroup(gl_panel_2.createParallelGroup(Alignment.BASELINE)
                        .addComponent(lblFecha)
                        .addComponent(comboBox_Dia, GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                        .addComponent(lblDe)
                        .addComponent(comboBox_mes, GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                        .addComponent(lblDe_1)
                        .addComponent(textField_Anio, GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                        .addComponent(btnX))
                    .addContainerGap(GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE))
        );
        panel_2.setLayout(gl_panel_2);      

        JButton button = new JButton("+");
        button.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
                if (textField_UbicacionNueva.getText().equals("") || !textField_UbicacionNueva.isEnabled() || !comboBox_Ubicacion.getSelectedItem().equals("Agregar Nueva")){
                    String message = "Ubicación nueva no disponible";
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(new JFrame(), message, "Dialog", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);  

                }else{

                }
            }
        });
        GroupLayout gl_panel_1 = new GroupLayout(panel_1);
        gl_panel_1.setHorizontalGroup(
            gl_panel_1.createParallelGroup(Alignment.LEADING)
                .addGroup(gl_panel_1.createSequentialGroup()
                    .addGap(6)
                    .addComponent(lblUbicación)
                    .addGap(5)
                    .addComponent(comboBox_Ubicacion, GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                    .addGap(11)
                    .addComponent(textField_UbicacionNueva, GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 91, GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                    .addPreferredGap(ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
                    .addComponent(button)
                    .addContainerGap())
        );
        gl_panel_1.setVerticalGroup(
            gl_panel_1.createParallelGroup(Alignment.LEADING)
                .addGroup(gl_panel_1.createSequentialGroup()
                    .addGap(9)
                    .addComponent(lblUbicación))
                .addGroup(gl_panel_1.createSequentialGroup()
                    .addGap(5)
                    .addGroup(gl_panel_1.createParallelGroup(Alignment.BASELINE)
                        .addComponent(comboBox_Ubicacion, GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                        .addComponent(textField_UbicacionNueva, GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                        .addComponent(button)))
        );
        panel_1.setLayout(gl_panel_1);
        setLayout(groupLayout);

    }

    public Cargador getCargador(){
        return new Cargador (this.getRuta(),this.getUbicacion(),this.getFecha(),this.getUsuario());
    }

    public String getFecha (){      
        return this.getAnio()+"-"+this.getMes()+"-"+this.getDia().toString()+" 00:00:00.000";
    }

    public String getUsuario (){        
        return this.usuario;
    }

    public String getRuta (){
        return this.textField_Ruta.getText();
    }

    public String getAnio(){
        return this.textField_Anio.getText();
    }

    public String getMes(){     
        String mes = null;

        if (this.comboBox_mes.getSelectedItem().toString().equals("enero")){
            mes = "01";
        }else if (this.comboBox_mes.getSelectedItem().toString().equals("febrero")){
            mes = "02";
        }else if (this.comboBox_mes.getSelectedItem().toString().equals("marzo")){
            mes = "03";
        }else if (this.comboBox_mes.getSelectedItem().toString().equals("abril")){
            mes = "04";
        }else if (this.comboBox_mes.getSelectedItem().toString().equals("mayo")){
            mes = "05";
        }else if (this.comboBox_mes.getSelectedItem().toString().equals("junio")){
            mes = "06";
        }else if (this.comboBox_mes.getSelectedItem().toString().equals("julio")){
            mes = "07";
        }else if (this.comboBox_mes.getSelectedItem().toString().equals("agosto")){
            mes = "08";
        }else if (this.comboBox_mes.getSelectedItem().toString().equals("septiembre")){
            mes = "09";
        }else if (this.comboBox_mes.getSelectedItem().toString().equals("octubre")){
            mes = "10";
        }else if (this.comboBox_mes.getSelectedItem().toString().equals("noviembre")){
            mes = "11";
        }else if (this.comboBox_mes.getSelectedItem().toString().equals("diciembre")){
            mes = "12";
        }

        return mes;
    }

    public String getDia(){
        return this.comboBox_Dia.getSelectedItem().toString();
    }

    public String getUbicacion(){
        if (this.comboBox_Ubicacion.getSelectedItem().toString().equals("Agregar Nueva")){
            if (this.textField_UbicacionNueva.getText().equals("")){
                return null;
            }else {
                return this.textField_UbicacionNueva.getText();
            }
        }else if (this.comboBox_Ubicacion.getSelectedItem().toString().equals("")){
            return null;
        }else {
            return this.comboBox_Ubicacion.getSelectedItem().toString();
        }
    }
}
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: please edit your post, select whole code then press {} code tags

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if there is any one best way to do this, but I see two possible ways:

One way is to allow outside classes to add an ActionListener to the btnX held in DatosArchivo by giving this class a public method for doing this.  Something like:

```
   public void addbtnXActionListener(ActionListener listener) {
      btnX.addActionListener(listener);
   }
```

Then the outside class can delete that JPanel from its display if it wishes.  The advantage of doing it this way is that the DatosArchivo need know nothing about the gui that's holding it.  When I did it this way, I also gave the DatosArchivo a public getBtnX() method to return the btnX JButton. This is so I can match the JButton obtained from the ActionListener's actionPerformed method's getSource method to be able to decide which DatosArchivo object to dispose.

For example:

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Component;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;

import javax.swing.*;

public class Foo002 {

   private static void createAndShowUI() {
      JFrame frame = new JFrame("Foo002");
      frame.getContentPane().add(new PanelCarga2());
      frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
      frame.pack();
      frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
      frame.setVisible(true);
   }

   public static void main(String[] args) {
      java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
         public void run() {
            createAndShowUI();
         }
      });
   }
}

@SuppressWarnings("serial")
class PanelCarga2 extends JPanel {
   private static final Dimension PREF_SIZE = new Dimension(600, 400);
   private JPanel datosArchivoContainer = new JPanel();
   private BtnXListener btnXListener = new BtnXListener();

   public PanelCarga2() {
      JButton btnAbrir = new JButton("Abrir");
      btnAbrir.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
         int index = 1;
         public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            DatosArchivo2 datosArchivo2 = new DatosArchivo2(index);
            datosArchivo2.addbtnXActionListener(btnXListener);
            datosArchivoContainer.add(datosArchivo2);
            datosArchivoContainer.revalidate();
            index++;
         }
      });

      JPanel topPanel = new JPanel();
      topPanel.add(btnAbrir);

      datosArchivoContainer.setLayout(new BoxLayout(datosArchivoContainer, BoxLayout.LINE_AXIS));
      JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane(datosArchivoContainer);
      scrollPane.setHorizontalScrollBarPolicy(JScrollPane.HORIZONTAL_SCROLLBAR_ALWAYS);

      setPreferredSize(PREF_SIZE);
      setLayout(new BorderLayout());
      add(topPanel, BorderLayout.PAGE_START);
      add(scrollPane, BorderLayout.CENTER);
   }

   private class BtnXListener implements ActionListener {
      public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
         Object source = e.getSource();
         Component[] components = datosArchivoContainer.getComponents();
         for (int i = components.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
            if (components[i] instanceof DatosArchivo2) {
               DatosArchivo2 datoArchivo = (DatosArchivo2) components[i];
               if (source.equals(datoArchivo.getBtnX())) {
                  datosArchivoContainer.remove(components[i]);   
               }
            }
         }
         datosArchivoContainer.revalidate();
         datosArchivoContainer.repaint();
      }
   }
}

@SuppressWarnings("serial")
class DatosArchivo2 extends JPanel {
   private JButton btnX = new JButton("X");

   public DatosArchivo2(int index) {
      setPreferredSize(new Dimension(200, 200));
      setBorder(BorderFactory.createEtchedBorder());
      add(btnX);
      add(new JLabel("Index: " + index));
   }

   public void addbtnXActionListener(ActionListener listener) {
      btnX.addActionListener(listener);
   }

   public JButton getBtnX() {
      return btnX;
   }
}
```

Another way to do this is to give DatosArchivo a reference to its containing class and then having the DatosArchivo object handle its own deletion.  The disadvantage to this is I believe that there is some increased cohesion.  For this to work, I passed a reference of the containing PanelCarga into the DatosArchivo's constructor, and then gave PanelCarga a public removeDatosArchivo that the DatosArchivo method will call, passing itself as a parameter:

```
public void removeDatosArchivo(DatosArchivo3 datosArchivo) {
   datosArchivoContainer.remove(datosArchivo);
   datosArchivoContainer.revalidate();
   datosArchivoContainer.repaint();
}
```

This whole example program looks like:

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import javax.swing.*;

public class Foo003 {

   private static void createAndShowUI() {
      JFrame frame = new JFrame("Foo002");
      frame.getContentPane().add(new PanelCarga3());
      frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
      frame.pack();
      frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
      frame.setVisible(true);
   }

   public static void main(String[] args) {
      java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
         public void run() {
            createAndShowUI();
         }
      });
   }
}

@SuppressWarnings("serial")
class PanelCarga3 extends JPanel {

   private static final Dimension PREF_SIZE = new Dimension(600, 400);
   private JPanel datosArchivoContainer = new JPanel();

   public PanelCarga3() {
      JButton btnAbrir = new JButton("Abrir");
      btnAbrir.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
         int index = 1;
         public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            DatosArchivo3 datosArchivo3 = new DatosArchivo3(index, PanelCarga3.this);
            datosArchivoContainer.add(datosArchivo3);
            datosArchivoContainer.revalidate();
            index++;
         }
      });

      JPanel topPanel = new JPanel();
      topPanel.add(btnAbrir);

      datosArchivoContainer.setLayout(new BoxLayout(datosArchivoContainer, BoxLayout.LINE_AXIS));
      JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane(datosArchivoContainer);
      scrollPane.setHorizontalScrollBarPolicy(JScrollPane.HORIZONTAL_SCROLLBAR_ALWAYS);

      setPreferredSize(PREF_SIZE);
      setLayout(new BorderLayout());
      add(topPanel, BorderLayout.PAGE_START);
      add(scrollPane, BorderLayout.CENTER);
   }

   public void removeDatosArchivo(DatosArchivo3 datosArchivo) {
      datosArchivoContainer.remove(datosArchivo);
      datosArchivoContainer.revalidate();
      datosArchivoContainer.repaint();
   }
}

@SuppressWarnings("serial")
class DatosArchivo3 extends JPanel {
   private PanelCarga3 panelCarga;
   private JButton btnX = new JButton("X");

   public DatosArchivo3(int index, PanelCarga3 panelCarga) {
      this.panelCarga = panelCarga;
      btnX.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
         public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            btnXActionPerformed(e);
         }
      });
      setPreferredSize(new Dimension(200, 200));
      setBorder(BorderFactory.createEtchedBorder());
      add(btnX);
      add(new JLabel("Index: " + index));
   }

   private void btnXActionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
      panelCarga.removeDatosArchivo(this);
   }
}
```